# Selenium WebDriverException when self.driver_.get("http://www.stockbroking.com.my")

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, synology

I have a Ken**** stock buying bot (Ken**** is a stockbroking firm) dubbed "Kenbot" that have been running for a year now which I have spent most of the time trying to iron out the bugs.
Until recently, I have a new traceback that I am stumped on. It only occurs occasionally on some days and not on others.

Kenbot runs via my Synology NAS on a docker image (selenium/standalone-chrome:latest) every morning before the market opens it will place orders for few stocks. It works via Selenium.

Right now I have no solution beyond having a @retry decorator that will reattempt to place stock orders if WebDriverException is encountered.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/order/downloadContractNote.py", line 23, in main
    with docker_selenium() as _, Kenbot(headless=True) as bot:
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/logs/logger.py", line 58, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/order/kenbot.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.bot.login()
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/order/kenbot.py", line 70, in f_retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/Drive/stock/order/kenbot.py", line 176, in login
    self.driver_.get("http://www.stockbroking.com.my")
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/volume1/homes/admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: headless chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

Comment: Hello, can you please add the code you used, so we can help you?

Comment: Did you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the program? For example, the error implies that the attempt to `self.driver_.get("http://www.stockbroking.com.my")` fails. Did you check that the website is available and online at the times this occurs? Did you notice any kind of pattern in when it fails? Did you try using a search engine to look up the error message? Did you try reading the Selenium documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumed you are using docker-compose, you can add the IP of `www.stockbroking.com.my`:

```
...
services:
  <app>:    
    extra_hosts:
    - "www.stockbroking.com.my:<add IP address here>"
...
```

Or, `docker run --add-host www.stockbroking.com.my:<add IP address here> ...`

Or using Python docker SDK as illustrated in the comment:

> container = client.containers.run('selenium/standalone-chrome', user =
> 'root', detach=True, auto_remove=True, environment =
> ["TZ=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"], ports={'4444/tcp':('127.0.0.1',4444)},
> **extra_hosts={'www.stockbroking.com.my': '999.99.99.999'}**, privileged = True)

Comment: Not docker-compose. '''container = client.containers.run('selenium/standalone-chrome',
                                          user = 'root',
                                          detach=True,
                                          auto_remove=True,
                                          environment = ["TZ=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"],
                                          ports={'4444/tcp':('127.0.0.1',4444)},
                                         privileged = True)'''  What does --ad-host do?

Comment: It inserts "www.stockbroking.com.my" with the corresponding IP into the container hosts file, so selenium can resolve the name during runtime. The same can be done via python docker sdk [extra_hosts](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html)

Comment: Here is what I did ``` container = client.containers.run('selenium/standalone-chrome',
                                          user = 'root',
                                          detach=True,
                                          auto_remove=True,
                                          environment = ["TZ=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"],
                                          ports={'4444/tcp':('127.0.0.1',4444)},
                                          extra_hosts={'www.stockbroking.com.my/': '999.99.99.999'},
                                         privileged = True)```

Comment: so you mean that when the error occurred there could be an DDNS error that map www.stockbroking.com.my to the ip 9.9.9.9 during self.driver_.get("http://www.stockbroking.com.my") ?

Comment: Remove the backslash `extra_hosts={'www.stockbroking.com.my': '999.99.99.999'}`. Does it works already?

Comment: Yes it is working. But the error above only happen occassionally - before posting to Stackoverflow I actually just manually ran it again and it worked at about 10am during the active trading hours. So I am not sure if extra_hosts actually fixed it or not.

Comment: Try take note of the IP `nslookup www.stockbroking.com.my`. When it fails again, nslookup and compare the IP address. If it keep changing, you need to find a way to use a static IP address for that host, if not there must be a DNS server on your network that can dynamically resolve the name to the ever changing host IP.

Comment: actually there are 2 ip addresses from the webpage. Does setting 2 extra_hosts actually improve reliability?